# Elevate application to administration by limited user

Tags: c#, wpf, uac

Currently i'm busy creating an application for an Siemens IPC. No problems with the application itself, but some difficulties with elevating the application to "Administator"

We need to have administrator rights to set PC date time, and we use a manifest to elevate the application to administrator.
No problems so far :)

But my problem lies in the fact the "normal" use is an operator which has limited access on the UAC, so i need to provide my administrator credentials to succesfully elevate the application.
I need this to happen automatically at startup, but the windows system does not allow me to use a startup schedular task of windows to run the program with the correct credentials.

Is there any other way to achive to run the application with administrator rights, without having to fill in the UAC credentials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add some code or show your working. Or see following reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why are you setting the date/time on the computer from a user-mode application? This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/).